# Как удалить символы из строковой переменной

Tags: php

Добрый день уважаемые столкнулся с проблемой удаления символов из переменной. Допустим переменная содержит следующию строку 8-999-777-8888-8888-999 ну эт к примеру. Мне каким то образом из этой переменной необходимо вырезать все "-" кто с подобным сталкивался подскажите решение.

Пробовал такой код

```
$ser1 = substr($ser,0,strpos($ser,'-'));
```

Но строка обрезается после первого -

Comment: `$ser1 = str_replace('-', '', $ser);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всем. Разобрался.

```
$ser1 = preg_replace("/-/i", "", $ser);
```